# Errors compiling owl .net api from Cognitum

Tags: owl

Downloaded api sources from here https://owlapinet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest . But got errors rebuilding. Mostly the following errors:
1. The type or namespace name 'owlapi' does not exist in the namespace 'org.semanticweb' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2. The type or namespace name 'OWLOntology' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[The complete error list here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLa1a.png)

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: You should include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the errors in the question itself. Although you have provided a link to an example or site, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: added error text and also uploaded image here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed one of owlapi.dll references (in Hermit project) and it worked.